# Why does clearInterval not work on my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, setinterval, clearinterval

```
<script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#pad").mousedown(function(){
            $(this).css("background-color", "lightgrey");   
            var timer = 1;
            var up_timer = setInterval(function(){
                timer = timer + 1;
                $("#pad").html(timer);
            },1);
        }).mouseup(function(){

            $(this).css("background-color", "grey");
            clearInterval(up_timer);

        });
    });
</script>
<div style = "height:500px;width:600px;background-color:grey;border-radius:4px;margin:0 auto;margin-top:10%;" id = "pad"></div>
<input type = "button" id = "done" value = "done">
```

Hello, my code is very simple. There is a big grey box, that when you hold down on it, it goes lightgrey. And when you do hold down, a number appears in the box and increases very quickly. I want the number to STOP increasing on mouse up, but for some reason the number carries on increasing, but the colour of the box does go back to grey.

here it is on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Bag47/1/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`up_timer` was declared with `var`. It doesn't exist outside the function it was declared inside.

Remove the `var` from `var up_timer = setInterval` and declare it in a wider scope:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var up_timer;
    $("#pad").mousedown(function(){
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript variables are scoped to the function in which they are defined, which means that `up_timer`is local to the function passed to `mousedown` and cannot be accessed outside of it.

Declaring the variable in the parent function makes it available throughout:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var up_timer;
    $("#pad").mousedown(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", "lightgrey");   
        var timer = 1;
        up_timer = setInterval(function() {
            timer = timer + 1;
            $("#pad").html(timer);
        }, 1);
    }).mouseup(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", "grey");
        clearInterval(up_timer);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `up_time` variable is not in scope in you `mouseup` handler. You needed to move it outwards in scope so it's still available in the `mouseup` handler.

New fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Bag47/2/

The important change is this, I've mode `up_time` upwards.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var up_timer;
```